# Bottleneck when using auth/admin/realms/myrealm/users in my app

Tags: java, jpa, docker, keycloak

I am running a script which requests the master token before requesting the list of users for a realm. I perform this request in a tight loop 100 times and output the time it takes to perform the `"auth/admin/realms/mine/users?first=0&max=1000"` request.

When testing with a locally installed keycloak docker, a single request is taking 4.0 seconds. If I run 5 instances of this script at the same time, a single request takes around 10 seconds. 
And if I run 10 instances, it jumps to 20 seconds before a reply is received.

Therefore, I have a serious bottleneck in my webapp on the page where I list all user information and was wondering how I might go about solving this problem.

I am running `keycloak 2.5.0.Final`. My java home is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-2.b15.el7_3.x86_64/jre`. `authorizationPersister = jpa`.

My script:

```
import requests

keyCloakUrl = "http://foo.bar"

for i in range(100):

    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.post(
        keyCloakUrl +"auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token", 
        data={
            "grant_type":"password",
            "client_id":"admin-cli",
            "username":"admin",
            "password":"admin"
        }
    )
    master_token = json.loads(r.content)['access_token']

    r = s.get(
        keyCloakUrl + "auth/admin/realms/mine/users?first=0&max=1000",
        headers={'Authorization':'Bearer '+master_token}
    )
    print(r.elapsed.total_seconds())
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak-mysql:2.5.0.Final

ARG db2

ADD deps/ /opt/jboss/keycloak/
RUN /opt/jboss/keycloak/import_utbud_realm.sh 

CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=2"]
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried measuring the time for the "auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" request. This is 0.1 seconds per request with only one instance of the script running and 0.8 seconds with 10 instances running.

Comment: Do you have a real case where you need to get the hole user list, 100 times the same list, 10 time that 100 times? And all in the same instant?

Comment: @Robert I'd be worried if 10 simultaneous requests to auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token are taking around a second as traffic increases to my site.

Comment: how many users do you have in 'mine' realm?

Comment: @ viniciusartur 500 users, each with attributes.

Comment: I found a similar issue in their tracker: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4137 - did you try a newer jboss/keycloak-mysql image like `2.5.5.Final` or `3.1.0.Final`? See https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak-mysql/tags/ for available tags.

Comment: I encountered a problem like this when a customer of us mapped some `@Lob` fields on the users. (Profile picture etc.) Although performance testing is really hard, you could check for bottlenecks on your system. Could you include some data you have on the users? (To resolve it there is not enough information in the post.)

Comment: how are you using your containers for your app @Baz?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is a silly observation, but did you try to increase you JVM heap in your docker configs? Like:

```
CMD java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintGCDetails $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar java-container.jar
```

There is a fantastic blog that explain the [memory issue with the JVM and docker here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/)